# Facebook Messenger API: Send Message to commenter on page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm having problems using the messenger API with a page access token to send a message to a user who has commented on a post on the page. I've done the following:

- Subscribed the page to a test app, which has a webhook monitoring the page 'feed' parameter.
- The webhook callback gets a result similar to this structure when a person comments on a post on the page:

  `{
    "entry": [{
      "changes": [{
        "field": "feed",
        "value": {
          "item": "comment",
          "sender_name": SENDER,
          "comment_id": COMMENT_ID,
          "sender_id": SENDER_ID,
          "post_id": POST_ID,
          "verb": "add",
          "parent_id": PARENT_ID,
          "created_time": 1492159609,
          "message": "hello"
        }
      }],
      "id": PAGE_ID,
      "time": 1492159609
    }],
    "object": "page"
  }`
- I then call the messenger API with the SENDER_ID above by sending a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` (as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#request)) with the params:

`recipient: {
        id: '10158402684940316'
      },
      message: {
        text: 'what up'
      }`

but I get the error: `(#100) No matching user found.`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The webhook for the page feed will give you app-scoped user ids, whereas the Messenger platform uses page-scoped user ids.

Answer (score -1):

I've just found a simple api for this case. Just use [Private Replies API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/private_replies)

```
POST /v2.9/{COMMENT_ID}/private_replies
```